# openvpn up/down scripts need full paths for iptables?

Tags: bash, vpn, script, iptables, openvpn

I am running a client install of openvpn on a raspberry pi with the latest raspbian os. everything is working except my route-up.sh and down.sh scripts. I can run them manually and they work, but the logs show they error out when being run by openvpn.

I have narrowed down the problem to needing full paths everywhere (paths are relative when executing manually, but I've discovered/have been told that they need to be full paths for when openvpn runs the scripts).

The problem is I can't find where iptables are for raspberry pi. I found the following in /sbin/

> iptables -> xtables-multi
>
> iptables-restore -> xtables-multi
>
> iptables-save -> xtables-multi

Which file does route-up.sh append my rules to? When I try to manually open them up to have a look (any of them), it is scrambled like I a missing a font. Any ideas?

FOR REFERENCE:
This is my route-up.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.0.134 table 10
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table 10
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d mydns.duckdns.org -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -d mydns.duckdns.org -j DROP
if ! pgrep -x "deluged" > /dev/null
then
   sudo -u pi deluged
   PID=$!
   sleep 3
   kill -2 $PID 2>/dev/null
fi
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: You should probably better ask this on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks. I will try that. I first tried in the networking stack exchange and they said try superuser, then again being redirected somewhere else. I'll eventually get it! thanks.

Comment: ^^ sorry for that adventure .. but this is defenately more Linux specific